# How to restart a coroutine after a websocket stream stops receiving data?

Tags: python, ccxt

I'm writing an asyncio application to monitor prices of crypto markets and trade/order events, but for an unknown reason some streams stop receiving data after few hours. I'm not familiar with the `asyncio` package and I would appreciate help in finding a solution.

Basically, the code below establishs websocket connections with a crypto exchange to listen streams of six symbols (ETH/USD, BTC/USD, BNB/USD,...) and trades events from two accounts (user1, user2). The application uses the library `ccxtpro`. The public method `watch_ohlcv` get price steams, while private methods `watchMyTrades` and `watchOrders` get new orders and trades events at account level.

The problem is that one or several streams are interrupted after few hours, and the object `response` get empty or `None`. I would like to detect and restart these streams after they stops working, how can I do that ?

```
# tasks.py
@app.task(bind=True, name='Start websocket loops')
def start_ws_loops(self):
    ws_loops()

# methods.py
def ws_loops():

    async def method_loop(client, exid, wallet, method, private, args):

        exchange = Exchange.objects.get(exid=exid)

        if private:
            account = args['account']
        else:
            symbol = args['symbol']

        while True:
            try:

                if private:
                    response = await getattr(client, method)()
                    if method == 'watchMyTrades':
                        do_stuff(response)

                    elif method == 'watchOrders':
                        do_stuff(response)

                else:
                    response = await getattr(client, method)(**args)
                    if method == 'watch_ohlcv':
                        do_stuff(response)

                # await asyncio.sleep(3)

            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
                break
        
        await client.close()

    async def clients_loop(loop, dic):

        exid = dic['exid']
        wallet = dic['wallet']
        method = dic['method']
        private = dic['private']
        args = dic['args']

        exchange = Exchange.objects.get(exid=exid)
        parameters = {'enableRateLimit': True, 'asyncio_loop': loop, 'newUpdates': True}

        if private:
            log.info('Initialize private instance')
            account = args['account']
            client = exchange.get_ccxt_client_pro(parameters, wallet=wallet, account=account)

        else:
            log.info('Initialize public instance')
            client = exchange.get_ccxt_client_pro(parameters, wallet=wallet)

        mloop = method_loop(client, exid, wallet, method, private, args)
        await gather(mloop)
        await client.close()

    async def main(loop):

        lst = []
        private = ['watchMyTrades', 'watchOrders']
        public = ['watch_ohlcv']

        for exid in ['binance']:
            for wallet in ['spot', 'future']:
                
                # Private
                for method in private:
                    for account in ['user1', 'user2']:
                        lst.append(dict(exid=exid,
                                        wallet=wallet,
                                        method=method,
                                        private=True,
                                        args=dict(account=account)
                                        ))
                
                # Public
                for method in public:
                    for symbol in ['ETH/USD', 'BTC/USD', 'BNB/USD']:
                        lst.append(dict(exid=exid,
                                        wallet=wallet,
                                        method=method,
                                        private=False,
                                        args=dict(symbol=symbol,
                                                  timeframe='5m',
                                                  limit=1
                                                  )
                                        ))

        loops = [clients_loop(loop, dic) for dic in lst]
        await gather(*loops)

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Answer (score 2):

let me share with you my experience since I am dealing with the same problem.

CCXT is not expected to get stalled streams after some time running it.

Unfortunately practice and theory are different and error 1006 happens quite often. I am using Binance, OKX, Bitmex and BTSE ( BTSE is not supported by CCXT) and my code runs on AWS server so I should not have any connection issue. Binance and OKX are the worst as far as error 1006 is concerned.. Honestly, after researching it on google, I have only understood 1006 is a NetworkError and I know CCXT tries to resubscribe the channel automatically. All other explanations I found online did not convince me. If somebody could give me more info about this error I  would appreciate it.

In any case, every time an exception is raised, I put it in an exception_list as a dictionary containing info like time in mls, method, exchange, description ecc. The exception_list is then passed to a handle_exception method. In this case, if the list contains two 1006 exception within X time handle_exception returns we are not on sync with market data and trading must stop. I cancel all my limit order and I emit a beep ( calling human intervention).

As for your second question:

> restart these streams after they stops working, how can I do that

remember that you are [Running Tasks Concurrently](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

> If return_exceptions is False (default), the first raised exception is
> immediately propagated to the task that awaits on gather(). Other
> awaitables in the aws sequence won’t be cancelled and will continue to
> run.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184226/catching-exceptions-in-individual-tasks-and-restarting-them) you can find info about restarting individual task in a a gather()

In your case, since you are using a single exchange (Binance) and unsubscribe is not implemented in CCXT, you will have to close the connection and restart all the task. You can still use the above example in the link for automating it. In case you are using more then one exchange you can design your code in a way that let you close and restart only the Exchange that failed.

Another option for you would be defining the tasks with more granularity in the main so that every task is related to a single and well defined exchange/user/method/symbol and every task subscribes a single channel. This will result in a more verbose and less elegant code but it will help you catching the exception and eventually restart only a specific coroutine.

I am obviously assuming that after error 1006 the channel status is unsubscribed

final thought:

never leave a robot unattended

Professional market makers with a team of engineers working in London do not go to the pub while their algos ( usually co-located within the exchange ) execute thousands of trades.

I hope this can help you or, at least, get you in the right directions for handling exceptions and restart tasks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use callbacks.

For example:

```py
ws = self.ws = await websockets.connect(END_POINTS, compression=None) # step 1

await self.ws.send(SEND_YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGES) # step 2
while True:
     response = await self.ws.recv()
        if response:
            await handler(response)
```

In the last like `await handler(response)` you are sending the response to the `handler()`.

This `handler()` is the callback, it is the function that actually consumes your data that you receive from the exchange server.
In this `handler()`, what you can do is you check if the response is your desired data (bid/ask price etc) or it throws an exception like ConnectionClosedError, in which case you restart the websocket by doing STEP 1 and STEP 2 from within your handler.

So basically in the callback method, you need to either process the data
or restart the websocket and pass the handler to it again to receive the responses.

Hope this helps. I could not share the complete code as i need to clean it for sensitive business logic.